# Annotate with full path to class

Tags: python, annotations, mypy

What is the correct way (if there is any) to annotate a variable/argument with a string containing full path to the type:

```
def make_json_response(obj: 'jfs.serializers.BaseModel', status=200):
    """Make a JSON response out of a Pydantic model instance.
    """
    return flask.Response(
        response=obj.json(),
        status=status,
        mimetype='application/json',
    )
```

I don't want to import `jfs.serizalizers` in the module in question to avoid circular imports.

PyCharm doesn't understand this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import a module only for type checking, you can import the constant `from typing import TYPE_CHECKING`.
Then you can wrap your import to `jfs.serializers.BaseModel` in an if-statement that only imports the BaseModel when TYPE_CHECKING is True.

TYPE_CHECKING is a special constant that is only True, if the types of your variables are checked. At runtime it is False.

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from jfs.serializers import BaseModel
```

Maybe you also have to add a `from __future__ import annotations` import.

Comment: "If you want to import a module only for type checking" -- I don't want to. You have answered to a different question.